WOW addon unit frame menu
I'm trying to open classic player unit popup (right click on player unit frame) to update my favourite addon for 11.0.0 but I'm kinda lost in the new blizzard_menu framework.
Addon looks like orbs from diablo and my original code looks like:
orb:SetScript("OnClick",function ()
    if GetMouseButtonClicked() == "RightButton" then
    ToggleDropDownMenu(1, 1, PlayerFrameDropDown, "cursor", 0, 0)
    end
end)

and I have no idea how can i rewrite this to new framework.
I tried to recreate it with guides on wiki and implementation_guide but nothing i tried works (get unit menumanager and then open it).

what is your question? you won't get a tutorial here. you need to ask a distinct question. what is the first thing you cannot solve?

how can i add a unit popup to my orb, what am I missing in adding a player menu popup
